I am unable to get Mongoose Aggregate method to work
I am building an api and I wanted to use the skip and limit methods in mongoose to handle pagination.
I would like to get the total document size along with the pagination data. Initially, I made two queries: one for the paginated data and the other for total document size. This is bad, right? I started searching if there is an inbuilt way to handle this on a single query. I came across aggregate method. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get it to work.
Here are my codes with two queries:
const page = req.query.page
 const {skip, searchlimit} = getPagination(params);
let transactionsData = []

const transactions = await TransactionModel.find({transactionOwnerId: user?._id}).sort({createdAt:-1})
  .skip(skip)
  .limit(searchlimit);

 totalDocumentSize = await TransactionModel.countDocuments({transactionOwnerId:   user?._id});

  transactionsData = transactions as transactionAttributes[];

console.log(transactionsData, totalDocumentSize)

Here, I tried the aggregate method:
 const me = await TransactionModel.aggregate([{
           $match: {transactionOwnerId: user?._id}
        }, 
         {
            $sort: {createdAt:-1}
         }
        
     ]);
console.log(me);

I believe that I am not applying the aggredate method properly. It is returning an empty array. How can I use it to apply the skip and limit methods and also get the total document size?

I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.

You should try with $facet.
Try this.I think it will work.
const me = await TransactionModel.aggregate([
      { $match: { transactionOwnerId: user?._id } },
      {
        $facet: {
          transactions: [
            { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
            { $skip: skip },
            { $limit: limit },
          ],
          totalDocumentSize: [
            { $count: 'count' }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]);

And then fetch each records using...
const transactions = me[0].transactions;
const totalDocumentSize = me[0].totalDocumentSize[0]?.count || 0;

Note :- Make sure to run this query inside async() function.

Thank you for trying to help me but it still returned empty array while as my old code with two queries work. Even if I copy the id of the document and paste it manually, it still returned empty array. Returns no data at all.

Please check if skip and limit(in your case searchlimit) variable are number and within range.

They are both valid because I am using the same skip and limit on the code that has two queries and it is working fine.

This works after I converted the object id to string. user?.id?.toString(). Thank you for your help.

@valve, I am glad to help you.Please accept the answer so that it can be used by the visitors latar.

try this!
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const limit = 10;

    const transactions = await TransactionModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $eq: ["$transactionOwnerId", { $toObjectId: user?._id }] },
        },
      },
      {
        $facet: {
          data: [
            {
              $skip: (page - 1) * limit,
            },
            {
              $limit: limit,
            },
            {
              $sort: { createdAt: -1 },
            },
          ],
          count: [
            {
              $count: "count",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ]);

    console.log(transactions);

